# How to get the absolute path of the executed jar?

Tags: java, maven, jar

How do I get the location of the executed jar? I found a lot of solutions but none of them work for me. When I run them in my IDE everything is fine. As soon as I build a jar file and run it with `java -jar myapp.jar` the output is like `/.../myapp.jar!/foo/bar`

I will run the code in `myapp.jar` - not in any library.

Location of jar: `/home/me/dev/myapp/myapp.jar`
Expected output: `/home/me/dev/myapp/`

I don't want the working directory as I would get with `System.getProperty("user.dir");`

Why I want to do this:

I want to store and load a file beside the actual jar. Like

```
/home/me/bin/myapp/myapp.jar
/home/me/bin/myapp/license.key
```

I want to avoid storing the file into some generic folder like `System.getProperty("user.home");`. And I don't want to store the file within the jar file.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file

Comment: @flafoux none of these solutions deliver my expected output.

Comment: The overall important question here is: Why do you need that info? Usually, it is not necessary to know the location of any JAR file. In fact, this question seems to be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose updaed my question

Comment: @Brettetete: do you package your required libraries into the executable jar?

Comment: @wero yes (15characters)

Comment: @Brettete would it be an option to place the libraries in a subfolder (as for instance offered by the Eclipse Runnable Jar exporter)?

Comment: @wero no (15 characters)

Answer (score 0):

`java.nio.file.Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath()` will return absolute path to current directory.

Comment: I quote my question here: "I don't want the working directory"

Comment: Try creating simple class which simply prints `Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath()` to stdout and create jar file containing this class. Then move this jar file to different folders and run `java -jar test.jar`. I saw name of directory where jar file is located printed to stdout. I assumed this is what you want.

Comment: `cd /tmp && java -jar /home/me/myapp.jar` would result in `/tmp/` - not what I want. I want `/home/me/`

Answer (score 0):

I use something along these lines:

[YourClass].class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()

Regards

Comment: Gives me the following result `file:/home/me/myapp/myapp.jar!/META-INF/classes!/`

Comment: I'm getting file:/home/me/myapp/myapp.jar What JRE are you using and how did you pack the jar?